# Hide a running app from Mac Dock without effecting App's UI (not using LSUIElement=TRUE)

Tags: macos, applescript, hide, dock

I wrote a little AppleScript 'runner' program that checks the last manual backup date of our custom invoice program. After alerting the user it is time to backup (and asking if they want to backup now) it runs the actual invoice program. I gave it the same icon as the main program, a similar name, and replaced the dock icon with my runner.

Everything works great except after the runner runs the 'real' program I am left with two Dock icons (the runner and the running 'real' program).

My original thought was to disable the real program from showing in the Dock and keep my runner running. I edited the real programs info.plist to hide it in the dock (LSUIElement=TRUE) but this also appears to hide the Menubar, minimize, close icons as well.

Can anyone suggest a way I might be able to just have 1 Dock icon, and have it indicate whether the program is running or not.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are leaving the runner application running after launching the real application?

Comment: Currently the runner exits after running the main program, but then the dock has the icon for the closed runner and the running app. What I want is is to behave like it is ll one app. I was just saying above that I had experimented with completely hiding the real program from the dock and launching or activating it from my icon (but that didnt workout to well using LSUIElement)

Comment: So you are leaving the runner app in the dock?  You can programmatically change the application's activation policy to set the LSUIElement equivalent while it is running, but if the app has been placed on the dock the icon will stay there.

Comment: Why not make the runner app a background app (LSUIElement=TRUE)? It sounds as though that's something that ought to be running in the background constantly anyway, so the user doesn't need to see its icon in the dock, and you can still put up dialogs from background apps. That way the user will only ever see the main app in the dock. Barring that, you might want to look into creating an app extension (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/). That way you'd integrate the runner into the app. That's a good bit more work, though...

Comment: I dont want my app running in the background all the time, and I want the user to only get a reminder when they think they are about to launch the real app (and have not backed up for a while). I just looked at your link to creating an extension and I dont really see how I could create an extension to perform this task as described either. The only way I can think of doing what I describe (and it sound really messy) is to programmatically switch dock icons. And if that is even possible, how to get the icon in the same location and how to restore the runner on real program exit.

Comment: I guess I'm not quite seeing the workflow here. How does the runner app 'know' that the user is about to launch the main app? Or is this a thing where the user never runs the main app directly, but always launches it through the runner app? In which case, why not recode the main app so that it checks to see if data is backed up before it tries to load any data?

Comment: The dock is fairly opaque; I suppose you could do as Red says and programmatically change LSUIElement, and then call `[NSDockTile display]`from your runner app to force a redraw of the tile (which would *theoretically* remove the icon from the dock, since the dock would now think the app is a background agent). But that seems like weird way to approach the issue...

Comment: Currently, the user clicks on the Dock icon to launch what they think is the real app, but are launching the runner app. Not sure how I would go about re-coding the main app as I didn't write it (open to suggestions though)

Comment: I do think that messing with what is displayed on the Dock programmatically is way too messy. I think you are correct, the only way to do it nicely is to somehow inject some code into the main app to have it check (I would also consider checking on program exit if that is easier).